# Fill in internet form using a pandas dataframe and mechanicalsoup

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, mechanicalsoup

I am using mechanicalsoup and I need to auto-fill the internet form using information from a dataframe, automatically.

The dataframe is called checkdataframe.

```
    br = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser(user_agent='MechanicalSoup')
    for row in checkdataframe.codenumber:
       if row in '105701':
          url = "https://www.internetform.com"
          br.open(url)
          for column in checkdataframe[['ID', 'name','email']]:
              br.select_form('form[action="/internetform.com/info.do"]')
              br.form['companycode'] =checkdataframe['ID']  #THIS INFORMATION SHOULD COMING FROM DATAFRAME
              br.form['username'] = checkdataframe['name'] #THIS INFORMATION SHOULD COMING FROM DATAFRAME
              br.form['emailaddress'] = checkdataframe['email'] #THIS INFORMATION SHOULD COMING FROM DATAFRAME
              response = br.submit_selected()
              soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

              table = soup.find('div', attrs = {'class':'row'})
              for row in table.findAll('div', attrs = {'class':'col-md-4 col-4'}):
                  scrapeinfo = {}
                  scrapeinfo['STATUS'] = row.div
                  scrapeinfo['NAMEOFITEM'] = row.label
                  scrapeinfo['PRICE'] = row.div
                  checkdataframe.append(scrapeinfo)
        
        
else:
        break
```

How can I make br.form['companycode'] =checkdataframe['ID'] this work, instead of

br.form['companycode'] = '105701'

br.form['username'] = 'myusername'

br.form['emailaddress'] = 'myusername@gmail.com'

I need to append the information that is scrape into the checkdataframe.
I need help, please.

Comment: Please format your code properly. Its very hard to understand your question right now

Comment: How is this hard to understand?  I want to use dataframe information in my fields, instead of typed information.

Comment: I want to send several items from a dataframe to a webform using python.  Can I do this in Mechanicalsoup?

Comment: Dynamic filling in webforms from a dataframe using Mechanicalsoup.

Answer (score 0):

Use selenium for this activity

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).